# Issue with kafka-node on docker node:10-alpine

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I created a test project for the issue.

https://github.com/ivandejanovic/test

When I try do build a docker image on Ubuntu 18.04 all goes ok, but when I try on macOS 10.13.4

I get this error:

```
> snappy@6.0.4 install /usr/src/app/node_modules/snappy
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory '/usr/src/app/node_modules/snappy/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/snappy/deps/snappy/snappy-1.1.7/snappy-sinksource.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/snappy/deps/snappy/snappy-1.1.7/snappy-stubs-internal.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/snappy/deps/snappy/snappy-1.1.7/snappy.o
  AR(target) Release/obj.target/deps/snappy/snappy.a
  COPY Release/snappy.a
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o
In file included from ../src/./binding.h:3:0,
                 from ../src/binding.cc:1:
/root/.node-gyp/10.2.0/include/node/node.h:53:50: fatal error: core.h: 
No such file or directory
 #include "core.h"  // NOLINT(build/include_order)
                                                  ^
compilation terminated.
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/app/node_modules/snappy/build'
make: *** [binding.target.mk:102: 
Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node- 
gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:237:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" 
"/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" 
"rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/src/app/node_modules/snappy
gyp ERR! node -v v10.2.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Could be related to this issue:
https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka/issues/292

Any idea how to resolve this on Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was the old node:10-alpine image that was using node 10.2.0. Once I deleted it my mac downloaded the latest image with node 10.2.1 and everything worked. My Ubuntu laptop didn't have the old image that is probably why it worked there immediately.